# Compute $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}$ in logarithmic space

Tags: numerical-methods, logarithms, floating-point

Let $x,y\in(0,\infty)^n$. Is there a clever way to compute $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}\tag1$$ by calculating $\ln\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}$ instead? My problem is that I need to build $(1)$ in a computer program and suffer from floint-point imprecision. Maybe we can use that $$\ln(x+y)=x+\ln\left(1+e^{\ln y-\ln x})\right)\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y>0.\tag2$$

Comment: "Logarithmic space" isn't a common term. It should be replaced by "logarithmic scale on axes".

Comment: Explain the initial problem you meet that make you think that taking a logarithm version it could be better... Is it a huge order of magnitude ?

Comment: All right. But what about their order of magnitude ?

Comment: The components of $x$ are approximately in the range $(0,1e24)$; on average they are approximately $1e19$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think working with a logarithmic scale will do any good.

Let us concentrate on the (weighted) arithmetical mean you want to compute.

In presence of several order of magnitudes among the $x_i$, I advise you to adopt an "incremental" strategy  (successive adjustments) :

1) Make "clusters" of $x_i$ by decreasing order of magnitude (for each cluster, give as compound weight the sum of the weights of its constituants)

2) For each cluster, compute its mean (with compound weights),

3) Make a compound mean of all these means with the compound weights.

Comment: Are the $y_i$ as well with different orders of magnitude ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I've got a matrix $z\in[0,\infty)^{3\times n}$ and $y$ is equal to a fixed row of $z$. Now $x_i$ basically is a convex combination of the $i$th column of $z$, but most of the $x_i$ are set to $0$ (say only 1 / 500000 percent of them are not $0$).